# What is mirroring a Tor directory

Tags: configuration, directory, mirrors

In the torrc there is 'uncomment this to mirror directory information for others, please do if you have enough bandwith'

I basically would have some bandwith free but my router is out of RAM. But this isn't  the question... Why is there an option DirPortFrontPage /etc/tor/tor-exit-notice.html?

Mirroring a Tor Directory doesn't not make you to an exit node, doesn't it? So what risks are if you mirror a Tor directory? Is it safe with the law to do it at home?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's a HTTP GET mirror just like `rsync` tool, but only from the network consensus: it caches the *cryptographically signed* answers from the main directory servers. The `DirPortFrontPage /etc/tor/tor-exit-notice.html` is just an `index.html` page for the browser that will just open your IP+port without any url specified. It's considered to be an informational page that it's a Tor exit node. My good advice to you - use a standard Apache(preferable) or NGinx index page to trick the DPI scanners. Some ISP's or censoring parties do scan actively for tor directory mirrors

Comment: Ok, but I'm not an exit relay when I'm mirroring a directory, and a directory is not an exit relay too, isn't it? So the confusion is, why is the tor-exit-notice.html for DirPortFrontPage specified?

Comment: you don't have to be an exit relay to sustain a mirror - and you should mirror it. Mirror and the exit are different roles, **not** mutually exclusive

Comment: So I can safely mirror without having trouble with the law. Thank you, you can edit your answer.

Comment: Mirroring a list of IP addresses digitally signed for integrity is legal everywhere: you're not mirroring any resources that can be blocked/banned/censored - you're just mirroring a set of signed lists. It's like hosting a dot-torrent file: **it's legal** - it's just a text file with a publicly available data and the irreversible hash of the file *whatever copyrighted it's contents are*